# Python - Save Excel Spreadsheet without the Data Connection

Tags: python, excel

I have a bunch of Excel Spreadsheets which are connected (by ODBC) to a database. 
I have a Python script which opens each sheets, calls RefreshAll() to update the data, does SaveAs() to puts the refreshed file in a shared folder.

But during this process I would prefer to remove the data connection, so that users can't call for another refresh of the data and also cannot manipulate the SQL Query to obtain additional data that they shouldn't access.

```
wb = xl.workbooks.open(file, 2, False, None, None, 'password')  # open workbook
xl.Visible = True # for testing
wb.RefreshAll()
wb.SaveAs(fileDest)
xl.Quit()
```

Comment: If before convert to csv?

Answer (score 0):

This works...

```
wb = xl.workbooks.open(file, 2, False, None, None, 'password')  # open workbook
xl.Visible = True # for testing
wb.RefreshAll()
for conn in wb.Connections:
     conn.Delete()
 wb.SaveAs(fileDest)
xl.Quit()
```